# Dell PVT-132T Tape Drive Install Assistance

Tags: dell, tapedrive

OS: Windows 2012 R2  all current updates are installed.
Server: Dell R710

I have an ancient Dell PVT-132T Tape Library. In the Device Manager I see the Medium Changer Device but missing the Tape Drive Device (should be a IBM ULTRIUM-TD3 SCSI Sequential Device).  I have tried to use the tape drive driver from Dell, using the .inf file.  It fails to install. Using the Device Manager >> Action >> Add Legacy hardware then browse to the LTO Drives and click on the inf.  The device is not installed.  Does anyone have a driver for this Tape Drive Device? Please advise if more information is required.

Thank you.